# java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: " "

Tags: java, numberformatexception

When I try to do this:

`total = Integer.parseInt(dataValues_fluid[i]) + total;`

It will give me an error message

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: " "
```

Some of the values are " ". So thats why it gives me. But I tried

```
int total = 0;
for(int i=0; i<counter5; i++){

if(dataValues_fluid[i]==" "){dataValues_fluid[i]="0";}

total = Integer.parseInt(dataValues_fluid[i]) + total;
}
```

I still get the same `java.lang.NumberFormatException` error.

Comment: Have you also got "" in your input (not space but null or empty strings)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm assuming that `dataValues_fluid[]` is an array of `String`s.  If this is the case, you can't use the `==` comparison operator - you need to use `if(dataValues_fluid[i].equals(" "))`.

So your `parseInt()` is attempting to parse the space character, which results in your `NumberFormatException`.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using `==` to compare the string to `" "`, do this instead:

```
if (" ".equals(dataValues_fluid[i]) { dataValues_fluid[i] = "0"; }
```

Note the difference between using `==` and `.equals()` with strings.  `==` does not work for comparing strings in Java - you have to use the `.equals()` method.

http://leepoint.net/notes-java/data/expressions/22compareobjects.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to compare strings using `equals`:

```
if(dataValues_fluid[i].equals(" ")){dataValues_fluid[i]="0";}
```

In general though, the more elegant way to do it would be to catch the NumberFormatException and set the value to 0 in that case.

Comment: yes i was thinking to catch the numberformatexception. and set it to equal to 0

Answer (score 1):

I think Andy White's link is enough for your purose, but if you needed another detailed explanation of why "==" operator doesn't work and what alternatives there are (actually there's a few), check this link out:
http://www.devdaily.com/java/edu/qanda/pjqa00001.shtml

Here's the API doc info on other equal methods:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the line that adds to your total in a try/catch block, so any invalid numbers will be ignored (you can log the error if you want to be informed about it).

```
try {
    total += Integer.parseInt(dataValues_fluid[i]);
} catch (NumberFormatException ignored) {}
```

This way you will ignore *any* non-numeric values, not only spaces and your program will perform well (to be also safe, log that exception or perform some double-checking when it occurs).

Nothing will be added to your total in case of invalid numbers, so your program will perform as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code.
The problem was the condition to verify your condition.
So I use a tringle verification to optimize some memory.

```java
int total = 0;
for(int i=0; i<counter5; i++){
total += Integer.parseInt(dataValues_fluid[i].equals(" ") ? "0" : dataValues_fluid[i]) ;
}
```

in the method u can use a "throws NumberFormatException " else

```
try {
  int total = 0;
  for(int i=0; i<counter5; i++){
   total += Integer.parseInt(dataValues_fluid[i].equals(" ") ? "0":dataValues_fluid[i]);
  }
}catch(NumberFormatException e){
  e.printStackTrace() ; 
}
```